# Integrating laravel sanctum with nuxt js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nuxt.js, laravel-sanctum

I am trying to build a `nuxt (v2.14)` app where i am using the `@nuxtjs/auth-next` package for authentication.
I followed the documentation and was successful in integration with `laravel-sanctum`. Now I get appropriate response when auth package calls `/api/user`. While calling the other api's through `axios` I'm getting 419 error

> CORS token mismatch

My code:

```
fetchData(){
    var url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/project/search';

    this.$axios.$post(url, this.selectedFields).then(response => {
     if(response.status === 200)
     {

     }
    })
}
```

Do I need to configure XSRF-TOKEN in axios headers?, as its the same package being used in authentication.

[Console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pADCW.png)

[Network screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4feb.png)

`nuxt.config.js`

```
export default {
  head: {
    title: 'App',
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'en'
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },
  components: true,

  buildModules: [
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
  ],

  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/auth-next'
  ],

  router: {
    middleware: ['auth']
  },

  auth:{
    strategies: {
      'laravelSanctum': {
        provider: 'laravel/sanctum',
        url: 'http://localhost:8000',
        endpoints: {
          login: {
            url: '/api/login',
            method: 'post'
          },
        }
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... can u show url in network tab ?

Comment: Also, your `nuxt.config.js` file would be helpful.

Comment: @KamleshPaul https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4feb.png

Comment: @RubalGulati it `419` error it's laravel common error